Type safety for array indexes in C
My program has a data layout such that some structs reference others:
struct vertex {
   float p[2];
};

struct line {
   int           whatever;
   struct vertex *p1;
   struct vertex *p2;
};

struct vertex vertarray[50];

Now I want vertarray to become a dynamic array, so the p1 and p2 references cannot be pointers anymore because vertarray can move to a different memory address when it needs to be reallocated (well, I could keep using pointers if vertarray is an array of pointers instead and I allocate fixed memory for each vertex, or if I update the p1 and p2 fields of all lines whenever vertarray is reallocated, but I don't like any of these two solutions for my use case).
The solution I wish to use is that p1 and p2 are integers instead, to be used as array indexes in vertarray. But, by doing so, I lose an important feature: type safety.
struct line {
   int   whatever;
   int   p1;
   int   p2;
};

For example, if I have a function for modifying the endpoints of a line:
modifyline(struct line *l, struct vertex *p1, struct vertex *p2);

Now, if I change references to indexes, the function prototype would become:
modifyline(struct line *l, int p1, int p2);

And by doing that, I'm losing opportunities for the compiler warning me if I'm doing something wrong when passing p1 and p2 (or if I do something very wrong with p1 and p2 anywhere in the code).
What I would like, of course, is a strong typedef behaviour:
typedef int tvertindex;  /*that is, if typedef had strong behaviour*/

That way, if I call modifyline() using a potatoindex (imagine I have a potatoarray unrelated to vertarray), or a plain int for the p1 and p2 arguments instead of tvertindex, I would get compiler warnings or errors (but typedef doesn't behave like this, so it's just a wish).
The usual technique for strong typing by enclosing a type inside a struct looks like it could increase the complexity and syntax of the code unnecessarily.
Do you have any advice for this? What would you do?
Thanks!

Other than being outside the array bounds, what could be "wrong" with p1 and p2? You could make the same mistake with pointers, and the compiler wouldn't warn you, either. You don't need type-safety checks, you need bounds checks.

To begin with, you could use size_t, or any unsigned type, to at least not get negative numbers. Second, always have out-of-bounds checking for your array indexes, that's really a requirement for all arrays.

Use typedef struct { size_t index; } tvertindex. You'll then have to use p1.index and p2.index when actually indexing the array.

@Barmar When using pointers, if the arguments to modifyline() are not pointers to struct vertex, the compiler will throw a warning. When using ints, it's easier to make a mistake and not getting a warning. With your second comment, enclosing the index in a struct, type safety is achieved, of course. But as I said, I'm not sure if this increase in complexity is worth it. I need to think about it.

@Someprogrammerdude Yes, I always use size_t for array indexes. In this question I used int instead for avoiding the discussion of whether array indexes should be signed or unsigned :-D

Is this actually the kind of mistake you actually make, passing the wrong kind of integer parameter to a function? Did the pointer version ever catch mistakes?

Among the usual approaches to this kind of problem is to make a consistent practice of using good names.  That doesn't assist the compiler in catching bugs related to using the wrong indexes, but it sure helps you avoid such mistakes in the first place.  For example, modifyline(line, point_index1, point_index2) seems plausible, and if you expect that kind of plausibility then modifyline(line, point_index1, potato_index2) immediately looks wrong.
